# Is it possible to crack any MD5 hashes (without salt)?

Tags: hash, password-cracking, md5

We all know currently `MD5` hash can be cracked but I was wondering if any hashes can be cracked since most crackers are searching in their database instead of cracking, so let's pretend we get a document that has near 1400 characters and we generate an md5 hash, is it possible to get the document by cracking the hash or the hash cracker can only crack short string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cracking" a cryptographic hash doesn't mean recovering the original document. Since there are an infinite number of potential original documents for each hash value, that's never possible. Cracking a hash means finding *some* document that generates the hash, whether or not it's the original one. And yes, it's possible that MD5 can be cracked in this way -- it's not recommended for use.

Comment: `And yes, MD5 can easily be cracked in this way.` only for low-entropy predictable values, the best preimage attack for MD5 still has complexity over 100 bits

Comment: @AndrolGenhald Yes, I've edited the answer to acknowledge this.